# Regex: match text not preceeded by any number of spaces

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to match a function call, let's call it `foo.bar`. I want to be able to avoid matches on lines containing this function call that I have commented out. This is PL/SQL so comments are denoted with '--'. There can be any number of spaces between the comment text and the function call. I have tried negative look behinds (`(?!<-- +)` and `(?!<--) +`) but those still match the commented lines. Any advice?

Comment: Are you using `^` and `$` to note the beginning and end of the line?

Comment: This combined with Simon Shine's advice led me to the solution: ```^(?!<--) +foo\.bar.+$```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look-behinds [cannot have a variable length](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> *[...]* The regular expression engine needs to be able to figure out how many characters to step back before checking the lookbehind. When evaluating the lookbehind, the regex engine determines the length of the regex inside the lookbehind, steps back that many characters in the subject string, and then applies the regex inside the lookbehind from left to right just as it would with a normal regex.

So another strategy you can use is to match the entire line, disallow comments in this match and match the function name with a capture group. Giving a concrete answer to this problem would probably require a bit more context.

Comment: I didn't know that! Thank you for your advice: looks removing the variable length lookbehind and  matching the whole line worked: ```^(?!<--) +foo\.bar.+$```

Comment: There's something suspect about `^(?!<--)`: The beginning of a line cannot easily be preceded by two dashes. How about [`^(?!.*--.*foo).*foo`](https://regex101.com/r/znsbUh/2)? It does have a false negative for `foo -- foo`, so it's not perfect.

Comment: The reason I did it the way I did was because comments in PL/SQL (the language of the document I'm working in) use a '--' format. So any lines that have been commented out will *always* have those two dashes in front, and that's exactly the type of line I'm trying to avoid. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: @Tmnsquirtle: What I meant with suspect was that `^(?!<--)` will look at the two characters previous to the beginning of the line. This is probably not right, since `^` denotes that there were no characters prior to that. Most likely it will always not match. (If it had any meaningful interpretation, you'd be describing the last letters of the previous line, but I don't think that's entirely possible. Perhaps it is in Perl regex.)